# Parametric way of filtering date rows

Tags: python, database, loops

I struggling hard already a week, I've tried bidirectional while loop and other dateutil stuff, but with no luck, every time my counters step behind or I'm hitting some other problem

I just want to the find most efficient way of filtering rows by year and month for summing money by month.

```
fls17 = [counter for counter in db_list if counter.year == 2017]
fls18 = [counter.date for counter in db_list if counter.year == 2018]
fls19 = [counter.date for counter in db_list if counter.year == 2019]

fls17_sum = sum([counter.money for counter in fls17])
```

and here is example of my data, which is already parsed, converted to datetime object and putted into dataclass

```
[CsvDateObject(date=datetime.date(2017, 2, 1), year=2017, month=2, day=1, money=71, counter=0),
 CsvDateObject(date=datetime.date(2017, 2, 1), year=2017, month=2, day=1, money=53, counter=1),
 CsvDateObject(date=datetime.date(2017, 2, 25), year=2017, month=2, day=25, money=20, counter=2),
 CsvDateObject(date=datetime.date(2017, 12, 1), year=2017, month=12, day=1, money=35, counter=3),
 CsvDateObject(date=datetime.date(2017, 12, 25), year=2017, month=12, day=25, money=35, counter=4)]

[datetime.date(2018, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2018, 3, 1),
 datetime.date(2018, 3, 25)]

[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)]

214
```

Ask me if you want to see a full listing of code which I wrote before

> ++++

That's my initial data

```
csv_list = [
        ['2019-06-1', 68],
        ['2019-01-1', 68],
        ['2018-03-25', 75],
        ['2018-03-1', 75],
        ['2018-01-1', 25],
        ['2017-12-25', 35],
        ['2017-12-1', 35],
        ['2017-02-25', 20],
        ['2017-02-1', 53],
        ['2017-02-1', 71],
]
```

> ++++

itertools.groupby() - looks exactly what I need ^_^

```
gl = list()
for k, v in groupby(db_list, key=lambda i: i.month):
    gl.append(list(v))
```

Comment: sorry I am a little confused here, I don't see any `money` data, also why can't you do a `sum` with a `group by` in the database?

Comment: @aws_apprentice
updated,

I have no database, idea to make it with just a python dataclass

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if I understand correctly this is what you want:

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)
second = itemgetter(1)

updated = [[datetime.datetime.strptime(first(l), '%Y-%m-%d').year, second(l)] for l in csv_list]

[[2019, 68],
 [2019, 68],
 [2018, 75],
 [2018, 75],
 [2018, 25],
 [2017, 35],
 [2017, 35],
 [2017, 20],
 [2017, 53],
 [2017, 71]]

d = {}
for _, g in groupby(updated, key=first):
    grouped = list(g)
    k = first(first(grouped))
    v = sum(second(group) for group in grouped)
    d[k] = v

print(d)

{2017: 214, 2018: 175, 2019: 136}
```

Comment: summing must be by month ;) but anyway thanks a lot! I already digged into itertools and functools libraries, so without understanding this tools it would be difficult to solve my problem, that knowledge already a half of completed task heh =)  

but yeah pandas seems more suited for that

Comment: you can simply change what updated returns to return the month when it formats each object